Redhat 8 enabling screen sharing during kickstart
During the kickstart install I would like to enable screen sharing so that there is no manual action required. That includes setting the following options:

Enabling screen sharing
Allow connections to control the screen
Setting the password
Enabling the network interface


When searching for which commands I need to use I wind up on gsettings and I am directed towards the following groups: org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc and org.gnome.Vino. However the value of these options don't seem to reflect what is configured in the UI.
 > gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc
org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc auth-method 'prompt'
org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc encryption ['tls-anon']
org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.vnc view-only true

[root@ford ~]# gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino && echo
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled true
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['none']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption true
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'

The offical documentation only shows the above graphical menu. After having tried to edit the values using gsettings set ... there seems to have been no effect. Fustratingly enough I had to run these commands on the physical machine because the program continued to give me an error:
su -
dconf-WARNING **: 11:14:39.392: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

It's unclear to me if it's even possible to automate this step during kickstart, or even change it via the command-line after the fact. Vino has been deprecated, but it still contains keys under org.gnome and neither changing remote-desktop.vnc or Vino keys seems to make any difference in the configuration. Is there anybody that can shed clarity on this?
